# How to let the list loop till it is empty or one value in the list(Dictionary) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, machine-learning

The program pulls the two output from respective list and forms a dictionary and find corresponding pair one on and the other off DateTime and store it into a df. However, it does not loop until the list is empty.

This is my current code:

```
import random, pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import difflib

olist = []
storedListOn = []
storedListOff =[]
storedListDevice = []
storedListAppliance = []
storeListCategory = []
knnoutputlist = []
ldate = []

label = ['Light1_ON','Light2_ON','Fan1P3_ON','Light1_OFF','Heater1_ON','Fan1P3_OFF','Light2_OFF','Heater1_OFF','Light3_ON']
date = ['2019-10-28 09:11:23','2019-10-28 10:15:12','2019-10-28 12:23:52','2019-10-28 15:11:23','2019-10-28 18:30:20','2019-10-28 20:12:32','2019-10-28 22:00:23','2019-10-28 22:11:12','2019-10-29 05:12:23']
device = '8655'

for i in label:
    knnoutputlist.append(i)
    knnlist = knnoutputlist[:]
    print(knnlist,'check 1')

for j in date:
    ldate.append(j)
    labeldate = ldate[:]
    print(labeldate,'check 2')

outputList = {i:j for i,j in zip(knnlist,labeldate)}

print (str(outputList),'check 3')

if(len(list(outputList)) > 1):
  for i in list(outputList):

      i == list(outputList)[0]

      print(i)
      skeys = difflib.get_close_matches(i, outputList, n=2, cutoff=0.75)

      if(len(skeys) < 2):
        continue

      if 'ON' in (skeys[0] and skeys[1]):

        print("Retrieve Error",'9')

      elif 'OFF' in skeys[0]:      
        print("Retrieve Error 2",'10')

      else:

        for key, val in outputList.items():

            if skeys[0] in key:
              storedListOn.append(val)
            if skeys[1] in key:
              storedListOff.append(val)   

        [outputList.pop(key) for key in skeys]

        klist1 = skeys[0].split("_",1)
        klist2 = skeys[1].split("_",1)

        ak1 = klist1[0]
        sk1 = klist1[1]

        ak2 = klist2[0]
        sk2 = klist2[1]

        storedListDevice.append(device)

        if(ak1 == ak2):

          storedListAppliance.append(ak1)

          if 'Light' in ak1:

              storeListCategory.append('Light')
          if 'Fan' in ak1:

              storeListCategory.append('Fan')
          if 'Heater' in ak1:

              storeListCategory.append('Heater')

        storeDF =  list(zip(storedListAppliance,  storedListOn, storedListOff, storedListDevice, storeListCategory))
        sdf = pd.DataFrame(data = storeDF, columns = ['type', 'OnTime' , 'OffTime', 'device', 'category'])
        print(sdf,'12')
        #ptcn.set_index('time', inplace = True)

        print(str(outputList),'6')

print("Current Dict Contain:",str(outputList),'11')
print('Length of dict:', len(outputList),'12')
```

The current result that i have:

```
      type               OnTime              OffTime device category
0   Fan1P3  2019-10-28 12:23:52  2019-10-28 20:12:32   8655      Fan
1  Heater1  2019-10-28 18:30:20  2019-10-28 22:11:12   8655   Heater 12
{'Light1_ON': '2019-10-28 09:11:23', 'Light2_ON': '2019-10-28 10:15:12', 'Light1_OFF': '2019-10-28 15:11:23', 'Light2_OFF': '2019-10-28 22:00:23', 'Light3_ON': '2019-10-29 05:12:23'} 6
Fan1P3_OFF
Light2_OFF
Retrieve Error 2 10
Heater1_OFF
Light3_ON
Retrieve Error 9
Current Dict Contain: {'Light1_ON': '2019-10-28 09:11:23', 'Light2_ON': '2019-10-28 10:15:12', 'Light1_OFF': '2019-10-28 15:11:23', 'Light2_OFF': '2019-10-28 22:00:23', 'Light3_ON': '2019-10-29 05:12:23'} 11
Length of dict: 5 12
```

The result I want is that the list only left with Light3_on and its DateTime but the result i got only gets 2 correct rows in df

The output i want:

```
      type               OnTime              OffTime device category
0   Fan1P3  2019-10-28 12:23:52  2019-10-28 20:12:32   8655      Fan
1  Heater1  2019-10-28 18:30:20  2019-10-28 22:11:12   8655   Heater
2   Light1  2019-10-28 09:11:23  2019-10-28 15:11:23   8655    Light
3   Light2  2019-10-28 10:15:12  2019-10-28 22:00:23   8655    Light

Current Dict Contain:{ 'Light3_ON': '2019-10-29 05:12:23' }
```

Comment: Can you please remove all unnecessary code and point out explicitly how the output should look like?

Comment: @VadimShkaberda I have made the changes to the code what the output I want if you are able to solve it will be awesome

Comment: It seems like what you want is to create a dataframe that lists the various devices, when they were turned on and off and what type they are, while leaving devices that were turned on but not off in the source dictionary. However, your code is doing a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with this and debugging it is next to impossible without understanding what you're actually trying to do. However, it's likely something that can be done in only a few lines of code.